# Entity Framework selection query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am making a simple application for insert, update, delete, select data with `Entity Framework`
I already made insertion, deletion and select all data.

Now I want to select with where condition with filter of two fields
**For ex :** I have table with

```
userid
username
password
email
```

Now need selection like `where email = "" and password = ""`

I know how to write query in SQL but having not clues with `entity framework`.
Also need to store this result in datatable and looping solution both for learning purpose.
This can help many beginners

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Linq To Entities with lambda expression:

```
var result = dBContext.Account.Where(a=> a.email == "" && a.password =="").ToList();
```

Using Linq To Entities the less fancy way:

```
var result = (from a in dBContext.Account
              where a.email == "" && a.password ==""
              select a).ToList();
```

Lambda expressions are used most of the time.
Some people find lambda's less readable.
I think it's more a personal taste that depends from your background.

**EDIT:**

dbContext should be replaced by the name you gave your dbContext/Entities when setting up your Entitiy framework EDMX or Code First Classes.

Account should be replaced by the name of your table/Entity

To loop and edit the results you can do:

```
foreach(var account in results)
{
   //do something with the properties
   account.email = "test@updated.com"
}

//store the changes again in the db
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: this seems perfect. i am not able to find dbContext

Comment: dbContext is the name of your Context.
You are using Entity Framework so normaly when setting up the EDMX or creating the Code First classes, You chose a name for your Context/Entities.

Comment: thanks for the response. works perfect, would like to know more if you can provide me some more examples for lamda syntax

Comment: There are a lot of examples on the internet.
[101 Examples by Frode Nilsen](http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php) is a good start. You can also download a project with all these examples [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). This will be a great help if you are new to LINQ or Lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Use linq ex:

```
List<User> result = dbContext.Users.Where(o=> o.email == "" && o.password=="").ToList();

foreach(User u in result)
{
// do stuff
}

User u = new User();
u.Email = "mail@mail.com";

dbContext.Users.Add(u);
dbContext.Save(); //I think its Save()..
```

Comment: can you elaborate the ans to store it in datatable and with looping ?

Answer (score 1):

Have to use Linq query like

```
var data= dBContext.Account.Where(a=> a.email == "" && a.password =="").ToList();
```

`.ToList()` will give your entire data that comes under your where condition or filter.
Now for that you return `DataTable` and easily apply a `for` condtion based on your `DataTable` values.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable tempData = (DataTable)grdRecords.DataSource;

var query = from r in tempData.AsEnumerable()
            where r.Field<string>("UserName") != "TestUsername" &&
                  r.Field<string>("Password") != "TestPassword"
            select r;

DataTable newDT = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

use linq query as follows

```
IList<Users> Users = dbContext.Users.Where(x=> x.email == "" && x.password=="").ToList();
```

then if you want to convert into DataTable just call following generic method do convert it

```
        public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)// T is any generic type
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
databasenameEntities db = new databasenameEntities ();

tablename exist= db.tablename.where(p=>p.email=="txtemail.text" && p.password=="txtpassword.text");

if(exist.count>0)

{

txtuserid.text=Convert.toInt32(exist.userid);

txtusername.Text=exist.username;

....

.....

db.saveChanges();

}
```

hope this may helpful.

Comment: i am getting error like Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<DatabaseModel.logintbl>' to 'DatabaseModel.logintbl'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) what should i use in tablename datatable name or database table name ?

Comment: you have to choose your own database entities name at databasenameEntities e.g.(if your database name is "abc" then generaly it suggest "abcEntities" when we create entitydatamodel db is the object we have created and "tablename" is the database table name suppose here abc database have tablename "table1" which have field like email and password.)