# How convert Sql query to Linq in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

can any one tell me how to write linq query using EF. My sql query is

```
select * from
    (select tr.Training_id, 
            tr.title,  
            tr.create_on,
            tr.modified_on,
            max(lo.created_on) as lastDate  
    from [trainig] tr
    join [training_video_log] lo 
    on tr.Training_id = lo.fk_trainingvideo_resource_file 
    and lo.fk_user_id = 1050 
    group by tr.Training_id, tr.title, tr.create_on, tr.modified_on) X
Where modified_on > lastDate
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to be more readable.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718392/entity-framework-selection-query) might help you with how to start with selecting your data

For the query above you are looking for something like this:

```
var result = from tr in _db.Training
             join lo in _db.Training_video_log 
             on tr.Training_id equals lo.fk_trainingvideo_resource_file

             where lo.fk_user_id = 1050 &&
             tr.modified_on > lastDate

             group new { tr, lo } 
             by new { tr.Training_id, tr.title, tr.create_on, tr.modified_on } into gj
             select new
             {
                 TrainingId = gj.Key.Training_id,
                 Title = gj.Key.title,
                 CreateOn = gj.Key.create_on,
                 ModifiedOn = gj.Key.modified_on,
                 LastDate = gj.Max(item => item.lo.created_on)
             };
```

Please look at Linq documentation to learn more.

Comment: @Gliad Green thanks for ur kind reply, but it was not working for me. Actually I want get all records from training table which are having entry in  Training_video_log where training.created_on > Training_video_log.created_on

Comment: @Rafi - Then please see my comment above about adding what you tried and also when you say not working you should say what - compile error/ exception/ unexpected results

Comment: it was giving compile time error. am using Visual Studio

Comment: @Rafi - do you still have a problem?